# how to make canvas operation faster (HTML5 + JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a big canvas (covering almost the whole screen) which contains colorful shapes.
there is also a color picker. every time a user selects a color using the color picker, I check if the selected color belongs to a pre-determined set of colors (a set of ten colors). If the selected color is one of the ten colors, I show only shapes of that color in the canvas and hide shapes with other colors. A simplified version of the code follows:

```
//R,G,B : selected color
pixel = context.getImageData(0,0,W,H);                  
for(i=0; i<pixel.data.length; i+=4)
    if ((pixel.data[i]==R)&&(pixel.data[i+1]==G)&&(pixel.data[i+2]==B))
        pixel.data[i+3]=255;    
    else
        pixel.data[i+3]=0;

context.putImageData(pixel,0,0);
```

So at any time I either show all colors or just one of ten colors. 
The code works fine. The problem is that it is very slow. Does anyone know how I can make it faster?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose that making the canvas smaller is out of the question?

Comment: could you post a sample image somewhere?  Knowing how it looks might suggest some optimisations.  Also, how is the canvas filled in the first place?  It might be simpler just to redraw it each time.

Comment: What kind of shapes are there (rectangles, circles, odd-shapes)?  Do the shapes move?

Comment: @markE I'd also wonder whether they're anti-aliased, because that'll cause the pixel values to be mismatched around the boundaries.

Comment: @Alnitak Good point. Without more info from OP, I think "retaining" each image shape+position and doing a complete redraw will speed things up since getImageData() and putImageData() work slowly--agonizingly slowly on mobile!

Comment: the shapes do not move. They are random and odd. The canvas is filled by a algorithm that creates random shapes.

Comment: Thanks everyone. To solve the problem, Instead of drawing on one canvas, I used 10 canvases and draw each color on a canvas, then hide and show canvases to hide and show different colors. I am wondering if this is a good solution.

Comment: @BaharS if you can remember what shapes you're drawing, so you can recreate them, you'd probably be surprised just how quickly you could redraw the whole canvas including only the ones you want.

Comment: Thanks, but the shapes are drawn using a very random algorithm, so I cannot recreate them.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few optimisations you can make that might help, but I'd have to say your overall approach is probably not optimal.  There may be other options if we can get more information about how the original image is produced.

1. cache the `.data` value - there's no need to dereference that property five times in each iteration
2. cache the length of the `.data` array, it doesn't change during the loop
3. use `===` instead of `==` to allow exact comparison without a cast

between them those might speed your code up by maybe 30%, if you're lucky:

```
var pixel = context.getImageData(0, 0, W, H);
var data = pixel.data;
var i = 0, n = data.length;
while (i < n) {
    data[i + 3] = (data[i] === R && data[i + 1] === G && data[i + 2] === B) ? 255 : 0;
    i += 4;
}
context.putImageData(pixel, 0, 0);
```